# memory management in objective-c for retain

Tags: objective-c

HI 
i have questions on Memory Management
If I alloc object  1 time then i retain 2 time And then release 4 time  &
then retain 1 time for same object. what will be  my final ans?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Crrrrraaassshh!

Comment: Alloc/retain/release is a bit like a dog on lead (or leash). You alloc your object - you put your dog on a leash. You retain twice - 2 more people come along and also put leads on your dog. The dog can't run away as it is now on 3 leads. Even if a take of my lead, the dog will not be free until all 3 leads have been removed. i.e. if you release the object 3 times it will be free'd. What you are saying is you want to release the object 4 times. Well i'm afraid after the 3rd release your dog has run off chasing squirrels and your 4th release will crash your app. You should read the apple docs.

Answer (score 1):

The object will be dealloced after the third release (when the `retainCount` hits zero) and the fourth `release` will be sent to a non-valid object, resulting in a crash.

If you want an object to exist for a little while after you've released it, you should look into the `autorelease` method.

Comment: `retainCount` can never hit zero....   though the retain count of an object can. ;)